# HTML Form data not being sent to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I understand there are a lot of other similar topics, but I can't understand whats going wrong with my code based on those. Here is my form code:

```
<form action = "handle_form.php" method = "post">
  First Name:<input type="text" name="name">
  <br /><br />
  Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastname" />
  <br /><br />
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
<br /><br />

  Password:<input type="text" name="password" />
  <br /><br />
  <input type = "submit"/>
```

And here is the code in my php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <body>
    Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see this failing unless you did something wrong somewhere. Unless, you did not close off the form. It `</form>` is not in there and "how" this is used.

Comment: Your code is working without problems. Just make sure you are posting to the correct php file, and don't forget the closing tag of the form

Comment: What's the issue you face with this code ?

Answer (score -1):

I will like to ask what the error message is. But like hamed  said, don't forget the closing tag for your form.  I will also suggest you add "required" attribute to your input fields, this will ensure that you are not sending out null values to your php script.

Telling us the error message could help explain your problem better.